# How to set the border color of a CircleItemRenderer

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

I have a linechart and dots showing the places where a datatip pops up. I can change the line to any color I want and I can set the inside color of the dot. But the border color still stays orange (from the default color). Someone knows how I can set this property easy?

this is the code:

```
<mx:LineSeries id="dayEnergieLineSeries" 
                    yField="number"
                    showDataEffect="{slideIn}" hideDataEffect="{slideOut}">
                    <mx:lineStroke>
                        <mx:Stroke color="#d3ce01" />
                    </mx:lineStroke>
                    <mx:itemRenderer>

                        <mx:Component>
                            <mx:CircleItemRenderer />
                        </mx:Component>
                    </mx:itemRenderer>
                </mx:LineSeries>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the docs:

> It renders its area on screen using the fill and stroke styles of its associated series.

So you'll have to assign a stroke to the dayEnergieLineSeries series.

```
[Bindable] private var _stroke:Stroke = new Stroke(...);

<mx:LineSeries id="dayEnergieLineSeries" stroke="{_stroke}"/>
```

or if you don't need the data binding, just set it as a style.

PS: There is a good chart explorer available here: http://demo.quietlyscheming.com/ChartSampler/app.html

Comment: The problem isn't to add a line to the LineSeries and the line already has the right color. But the data points that are on the line have the wrong color. I want them to be the same color as the line

Comment: The CircleItemRenderer uses the stroke of the series to draw itself, so you'll need to set a stroke on the series. This will not only affect your linestroke, but also the data point stroke. Check the sources (right click) of the link I posted. There are some helpful code examples there.

Comment: Well that example isn't using datatips and isn't using the dots where i'm talking about. But I now have it working so thanks for pointing me in the right direction!